# what to do if I have two different models for same data?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, model

There's two regression models for same data.
The two are known very precise before but now they are generating conflicting predictions.

In this case how can i handle this?
Should i perform stepwise/forward/backward model selction? or do bayesian/frequentist model averaging?